# eclipse not recognizing dependency sources and scala docs

Tags: scala, ide, sbt

I have the eclipse plugin for sbt to generate eclipse project files. After the project's generated and imported, everything seems fine except for being unable to view the sources and scala docs. When I click on a reference, eclipse says the source cannot be found and I get an option to change attached source. However, the attached source is the correct file already (Ex. junit-source.jar). Eclipse still complains the class source code does not exist. Is anyone else having this problem?

Answer (score 1):

from the [Using sbteclipse](https://github.com/typesafehub/sbteclipse/wiki/Using-sbteclipse) documentation

```
EclipseKeys.withSource := true
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to set it in the build.sbt file as @David suggests, you can do, from the command line:

```
sbt "eclipse with-source=true"
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your problematic dependency has been compiled with stripped debug info. Recompile sources with -g flag and check whether this work for you.